# Android::Xoom: Camera Preview Orientation

Tags: android, camera, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, preview

I am trying to work with camera preview..

In the manifest file, for the activity I have set screenOrientation as landscape.
Also,  android:minSdkVersion is set to 10.
I am using Motorola xoom with Android version 4.0.4 for testing.

In the activity code, I see that I am getting "0" for
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

Also, info.orientation is returning 0; [where info is Camera.CameraInfo.]

However, I am still not sure that the camera preview is launched in landscape mode. 
How to cross verify in which mode the camera preview is launched / how to set the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
     if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
     int rotation = 0;
     if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
     } else {  // back-facing camera
         rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
     }
```

Can use the the above method of Camera.Parameters and know the orientation. Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29)

Comment: Hi, Thank You. I quickly tired set the rotation value in Camera.parameter to different values ( 90,180,270). It seemed to have no impact. I will try implementing onOrientationChanged and see if it works. Thanks for your quick attention and detailed response including code snippet. setRotation doc. says it works for Camera.PictureCallback, surprised that they did not mention PreviewCallback.  Will try out though.